# Qt embedded configure static and shared simultaneously

Tags: qt, configure, qtembedded

Is there a way to configure qt as static and shared libs simultaneously?
Qt only allows to use configure options -static and -shared, but there is no something like -static-and-shared.
Thank you for advance!

Comment: I think the only way is to simply build them twice and then build each project against those kits

Answer (score 0):

You need to build Qt twice, once configured -static, once configured -shared. You can do out-of-source builds so that you won't have to duplicate the source files. On Windows (jom is provided with Qt Creator, on Unix use gmake instead of jom):

```
mkdir qtstatic
cd qtstatic
c:\qt\5.2.1\configure -static ...
jom
cd ..
mkdir qtshared
cd qtshared
c:\qt\5.2.1\configure -shared ...
jom
cd ..
```